# Elm: preserve type of values in HTML select?

Tags: elm

In AngularJS, `ng-options` lets one specify an array of any values, not just strings, while preserving types. For example, I might create an HTML `select` using `ng-options` over an array of integers. When an option is selected, the *integer* value is placed into the model—no string-to-int conversion necessary.

In Elm, an option's `value` attribute accepts only a string, and thus the `select`'s `onInput` event sends back a string. Then I have to manually convert it to an int.

Does Elm have any equivalent to AngularJS's `ng-options`? Or any way to use a `select` with arbitrary, even non-scalar, values?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure you'd want to use it, but I did make exercise of this question in the form of a blog and a package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't really a way to do this. You're going to have to parse from a string to your desired type and back. You *could* wrap a `<select>` with [Prism](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/arturopala/elm-monocle/latest/Monocle-Prism)-based API.

Give me a couple hours and I'll write a tiny library for that after work... :D

EDIT:

Package - http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/toastal/select-prism/latest

Blog Post - https://toast.al/posts/softwarecraft/2017-01-13_playing-with-prisms-for-the-not-so-isomorphic

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm new to Elm and hadn't encountered Prism yet, so I'm definitely going to study this more. Thanks for the blog post too!

Comment: Take it with a grain of salt. Optics are not considered a best practice by some FP people--others love it. You could easily re-implement this library with an explicit get/set parameters rather than passing in a Prism, but where's the fun in learning something new in that??

Answer (score 3):

You might also be interested in my `elm-select` helper library.  It doesn't do all that cool Prism / Lens stuff, but it might be simpler in some cases:

http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/lgastako/elm-select/1.0.0/Select

Full example code here:

https://github.com/lgastako/elm-select/blob/master/src/Main.elm

Comment: That's pretty good too. I'm livid that you thought Lenses and Prisms were "cool". :)

Comment: This is great! I'm accepting @toastal's answer because of its depth, but honestly I'll probably end up using your library since it's so simple. Thanks!